# Automatically updating keys in relational tables

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables 'users' and 'orders' with the same user_id KEY, and I'd like to know if I update the user_id in one table, how do I get it to update in the other table automatically?

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY(id),
KEY(user_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE orders(
user_id VARCHAR(15),
//otherStuff,
KEY(user_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: How is it possible that user_id has been changed?

Comment: If the user decides to update their name for example.

Comment: create another field `name`, and in table `orders` refer to `users.id` field

Comment: There is no problem with using NATURAL KEYS. However, for *most purposes* (pretty much with the exclusion of a LOOK-UP TABLE) I find that using SURROGATE KEYS is cleaner and *more consistent*. Even though the key can be changed in the model under (hopefully) ACID guarantees, unless *every external reference* is also changed, there will now be "dead" or "crossed" references. (I am not saying that the PK *should* be exposed as such, but it often is.) If it is expected that the PK *will* change (not *can* change), then I would consider it suspect as a PK -- it doesn't identify, it describes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, i recomend use InnoDB engine, not MyIsam.

InnoDB support foreign keys, in the create table stament include "ENGINE=InnoDB;"

Foreign keys enforce referential integrity between tables i.e. if you try to `INSERT` an order with a non-existent user id the system will throw an error.

The foreign key can be a reference case on change, ex, for change id in the reference table can be:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
   user_id VARCHAR(15),
   //otherStuff,
   KEY(user_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
     ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This ON UPDATE CASCADE, change the value of user_id in case of change.

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM engine doesn't support foreign keys, so I guess you'll have to use triggers:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER abc AFTER update ON orders FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET user_id = NEW.user_id WHERE user_id = OLD.user_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You'll also need a second trigger that triggers after update on `users` table.

Comment: Then you could use a foreign key with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause.